# VS memory profiler shows decreasing heap size without any GC occuring

Tags: c#, visual-studio, garbage-collection, memory-profiling

How can .NET managed heap decrease in size without GC occuring? Or should I suspect that Visual Studio 2017 Memory Usage Diagnostic Tools are not 100% reliable?

I'm investigating memory footprint of some loop in my code. So I put breakpoint inside loop and on each hit of the breakpoint I took memory snapshot via Visual Studio 2017 Memory Usage Diagnostic Tools. However instead of seeing addition of objects that are clearly created in the loop I see that objects and memory is 'vanishing':

[image]

It can be seen that no GC occured between the snapshots, yet the heap size decreased?
Any ideas what can be causing this?

Comment: Btw. by logging GC.CollectionCount(0) it can be seen that the timeline does not show all the GC runs (probably just those exceeding some duration threshold?). However I can still observe the described phenomenon even if the GC.CollectionCount(0) reported count does not change

Comment: The graph does not show gen#0 collections, they happen too often.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant - that's a valuable info. Is there any reason for heap size to be shown as decreased even if neither gen0 collection occurect? (verified by logging GC.CollectionCount(0))

Comment: I suppose it could change while the finalizer thread is busy chomping away on the freachable queue.  No real idea if such objects are included.